# Error running TestNG - Unable to find the Application Name with lookup

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, cucumber, testng

I'm trying to running some `Cucumber` functional tests configuring `TestNG` in IntelliJ IDE.
Since the functional tests already existed in the project (and they were working) and I'm just trying to run them it must be some configuration issue.

In the Run/Debug configuration I created a new "`TestNG`" running configuration, where I setted

```
- the class I want to run (containing the functional tests)
- the VM options: -ea -Dproject.parent.version="2.78.0-SNAPSHOT" -Ddocker.image.env=dev -Dcucumber.options="classpath:com/[...]/providerResponse.feature:11"
- the classpath of the module
- the JRE
- the build maven command: clean install -P run-automated-test -Dmaven.test -Dmaven.test.skip.exec=true
```

where run-automated-test is defined in this way:

```
<profile>
    <id>run-automated-test</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Overwrite resources with functional resources -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/functional-tests-resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

When I run it I have this error message:

```
[TestNG] Running:
C:\Users\[...]\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\temp-testng-customsuite.xml
ERROR - Unable to find the Application Name with lookup
INFO - Creating new oracle
INFO - Creating new oracle initializer for the artifact=Artifact{uuid='c5cc7131-4caa-4959-87d2-f7d32c37b1de', groupId='com.[...].gateway', artifactId='accommodation-gateway', version='2.78.0-SNAPSHOT'}
INFO - Creating new module for the artifact=Artifact{uuid='c5cc7131-4caa-4959-87d2-f7d32c37b1de', groupId='com.[...].gateway', artifactId='accommodation-gateway', version='2.78.0-SNAPSHOT'}
INFO - build: ProgressMessage{id=null, status=null, stream=Step 1/2 : FROM accommodation-gateway, error=null, progress=null, progressDetail=null}
INFO - build: ProgressMessage{id=null, status=null, stream=
, error=null, progress=null, progressDetail=null}
ERROR - Error starting functional test containers
```

The temporary file "temp-testng-customsuite.xml" contains:

```
<suite name="Default Suite">
  <test name="accommodation-gateway-parent">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.[...].FunctionalSetUp"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
   <!--  accommodation-gateway-parent  -->
  </suite>
<!--  Default Suite  -->
```

Comment: **1)** What does your custom profile `run-automated-test` define? **2)** Is this a typo `-Dmaven.test` or is there some action behind in you project? **3)** Both error messages might come from some custom code (did not find an exact match with Google). You might run Maven on command-line with the parameters you mention and adding option `-X` (for debug mode) to see where they are comming from. This might narrow the origin a bit.

Comment: I updated my description with the answer at your point number 1. About the number 2 unfortunately I really don't know, but I guess it's a typo (I'm just following someone else's instructions and that someone is no more available for clarifications)

Comment: **1)** Ok. Seems it copies only some resources. **2)** Ok. Take it as typo. What about point **3)**?